# how to set ParameterDirection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, prepared-statement

In my code I want to assign Parameter Direction but do not know how to do.

```
  Dim sqlParam(0 To 3) As SqlParameter
  sqlParam(0) = New SqlParameter("@reg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
  sqlParam(0).Value = reg
  sqlParam(1) = New SqlParameter("@action_code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)
  sqlParam(1).Value = action_code
  sqlParam(2) = New SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40)
  sqlParam(2).Value = Session("user_code").ToString()
  sqlParam(3) = New SqlParameter("@@ret_val", SqlDbType.[Char], 1, )
```

I want to assign ParameterDirection of "@@ret_val".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're calling a stored procedure, and are interested in its return value:

```
sqlParam(3).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
```

If it's an output parameter, try:

```
sqlParam(3).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

Or check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx).